# Getting force close while loading HD images from url

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am facing problem while loading image from url. The image url contains HD image and it sets to **ImageView**. I am getting below error.

```
    java.lang.OutofMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget.
```

The application has many HD images to display. I also need to display HD images from local resource. Can anybody help me to resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Pranav just google "android OutOfMemoryError" & u get the solution right there.For now try http://stackoverflow.com/a/4134307/437703 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/4657285/437703

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have already tried with above links but sometime it gets force close. I get the image url from the web service using JSON but the actual image size is more than 5 MB. So, still it gets force close sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to scale your image before setting it to image view. Follow these links to avoid your error:

[OutOfMemory error while joining large images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213690/outofmemory-error-while-joining-large-images)

[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

[Out of Memory Error while using many bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928353/out-of-memory-error-while-using-many-bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

Android apps has a memory limit. Try to optimize the images.